# Jenkins not processing Apex pages

Tags: visualforce, deployment, jenkins

This is not exactly related to an issue **in** Salesforce but asking anyway. I had build scheduled in Jenkins to move changes to our QA Salesforce org. Everything is getting moved except for Visualforce pages and if a component has a dependency on any Apex page, the build will get failed. I checked in my bitbucket and the vf pages are included but just not getting to Jenkins. Is there a configuration setup that I missed ?

[image]

Comment: Do you have that page listed in your package.xml? and is it in the pages folder? That object is dependent on that page and it needs to be present.

Comment: The apexpage was not listed in the package.xml. Its working now. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Programatic, The apexpage was not listed in the package.xml.